# Center Allign Text on Button

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a button like

```
<Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_someid"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:shadowColor="#e1e1e1"
            android:shadowDx="0"
            android:shadowDy="0"
            android:shadowRadius="5"
            android:background="@color/bstate"
            android:enabled="false"
            android:gravity="center"

            android:text="@string/ABCDEFG"
            android:textColor="@color/btstate"
            android:textSize="16sp" />
```

and it is appearing like

[image]

how can i make the text center align

Regards

Comment: checked ur code exactly, its working fine..

Comment: im my emulator its showing like this :(

Comment: hmm try width as wrapcontent..

Comment: post your complete xml file

Comment: posted the complete xml

Comment: did you styling, or theme xmls?

Comment: yup just to change the color of buttons on state enabled and disabled

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i just cannot believe it, after hours of hair pulling i closed the eclipse went out came back started eclipse and things were just as they were supposed to be that is text was center alligned.

Answer (score 2):

Your code works perfectly, try to change your gravity like

```
<Button
            android:id="@+id/select"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="@string/btn_selectcontact_title"
            android:background="@color/button_bg_state"
            android:textColor="@color/button_state"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical" --> similar to center
            />
```

Comment: nope same as center, i have updated the question to include the style im applying for background color change

Answer (score 1):

add this to your **button** `android:gravity="right|center_vertical"`

```
<Button
            android:id="@+id/select"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="@string/btn_selectcontact_title"
            android:background="@color/button_bg_state"
            android:textColor="@color/button_state"
            android:gravity="right|center_vertical <!-- <HERE -->
            />
```

Answer (score 1):

If your button is in LinearLayout then just set ***gravity*** ***center*** to your button.

```
android:gravity="center
```